# Is there a builtin way to create a keyof literal in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to ensure that I'm using the valid keys on an type. I can use keyof for this, but it seems I need to create a const first:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  let open: keyof MyComponent = "open";
  if (changes[open]) {
    // ... do something
  }
}
```

I can create a function to force this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes[this.keyOf<MyComponent>("open")]) {
    // ... do something
  }
}

keyOf<T>(key: keyof T) {
  return key;
}
```

But it seems like there should be a more language based way to do this.

Comment: How is the type `SimpleChanges` defined?  Is it true that each key of `SimpleChanges` must be a key of `MyComponent`?  Or is there some other constraint?

Comment: SimpleChanges is part of Angular 6: interface: `SimpleChanges {
    [propName: string]: SimpleChange;
}`.  and is one place this comes up, but.  Mostly, I'm trying to ensure this kind of thing is refactor-proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can rewrite the method signature of `onChanges` to accept `changes` of a wider type than `SimpleChanges`, it will work for you.  For example, something like this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: Partial<Record<keyof MyComponent, SimpleChange>>) {
  if (changes.open) {
    // ... do something
  }
}
```

where `Partial<Record<keyof MyComponent, SimpleChange>>` means "an object which may have keys that match those of `MyComponent` and whose properties, if present, are `SimpleChange`".  This is a supertype of `SimpleChanges = { [propName: string]: SimpleChange; }`, which means "an object where every `string`-valued key has a property of type `SimpleChange` associated with it".

If you can't rewrite the method signature, then you can do the widening inside the method, but that is similar to your previous workaround in that you need to define a new constant:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  const widerChanges: Partial<Record<keyof MyComponent, SimpleChange>> = changes;      
  if (widerChanges.open) {
    // ... do something
  }
}
```

Anyway, hope that makes sense and helps.  If that doesn't meet your needs and you need some angular-specific help, you might want to add an `angular` tag to this question so it reaches different eyes.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

jcalz answer provides the key (and so I marked as correct, thanks!), However, I'm adding a bit of refinement:
If I create an alias type:

```
type SimplerChanges<T> =  Partial<Record<keyof T, SimpleChange>>;
```

I can get away with:

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimplerChanges<MyComponent>) {
    if (changes.open) {
      // do something 
    }
  }
```

Not entirely sure why, since I'm narrowing what is acceptable in the method from this:

```
export interface SimpleChanges { [propName: string]: SimpleChange;  }
```